# When will Javascript garbage collector delete variables that are covered by closure relations?

Tags: javascript, plotly, garbage-collection, race-condition

I'm receiving chunks of data asynchronrously via SSE and it is slowly but surely populating a dictionary `{UPD.x, UPD.y}`, whose contents I want to display with ploty.js. I want to see the graph steadily update as more chunks arrive.

I do the plotly calls similar to this

```
eventSource.onmessage = function(event) { 
   const data = json.parse(event.data);
   const UPD = data.upd;
   Plotly.update (PLOTTER, UPD, [0]);
}
```

where PLOTTER is global in the calling program. My thought is that while UPD is local to that function, the update command copies the reference as `PLOTTER.data = UPD` and so UPD should survive any garbage collection as long as PLOTTER stays alive at least until the next batch of data arrives, when the old UPD would get garbage collected.

A) Do I have that correct?

B) Taking this one step further, I really just want to be sure to display the last graph, I don't really care if I "miss" some plots of partial data. If new data has arrived since the last promise to Plotly.update() was issued then I'd really just want to blow off that earlier call. I think a solution to that could be to make UPD itself global to the function. What are the potential downfalls to that? Worst case that I can see is that it could result in a few extra calls to Plotly.update if the data arrives ahead of the plot. But maybe there could be an obscure race condition if UPD updates in the middle of a plot...

Comment: As long as you don't use weak references (like WeakMap) you don't have to think about data getting accidentally garbage collected

Comment: "*a solution to that could be to make UPD itself global to the function*" - I'm not really sure what you think is a problem that needs a solution here, but I also don't understand what you mean by "*global to the function*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the update command copies the reference as `PLOTTER.data = UPD` and so UPD should survive any garbage collection as long as PLOTTER stays alive. Do I have that correct?

No, you really need to distinguish between the `UPD` *variable* and the *object* that is referenced by `data.upd`, `UPD` and `PLOTTER.data`.

The `UPD` variable itself will get garbage-collected as soon as the `onmessage` function ends, just like the `event` and `data` variables. This will remove one reference from `UPD` to the object, and since the `data` object is no longer referenced, another reference from its `.upd` property to the object.

The object that was previously referenced multiple times is however still referenced from the `.data` property of the `PLOTTER` object, and as that seems to be a global variable (or at least a variable closed over by the `eventSource` listener), it will not be garbage-collected.

Comment: The reference to global UPD was partly in case there was a GC issue. And you've confirmed there is not. And partly for a more subtle point. Each UPD gets better and better over time and the last one is best. If the UPD is local then each plot to Plotly will make a different plot. And I guess it's even possible the plots could arrive in different orders so the plot could go good to bad to better, say. If the UPD was global then necessarily it would get better over time. But the flipside is that sometimes the Plotly.update will be a complete duplicate of the previous.